# notebook-style side tabs in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

Is there an open-source vertical side tab bar similar to the one in the '2Do' app?
I'm looking for something that looks like notebook tabs that control a detail view and can be moved around, be deleted or edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get creative, but a UISegmentedControl in a view, then rotate the view 90degrees. For the text, you would draw into a tall narrow view one character after the other so the text goes down. create an image, and use that for each segment's image. Not sure how it would look, but you'd get all the logic in UISegmentedControl obviously for free.